# Total value in the table/ card does not tally

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

The code below works fine to sort the new customer, however the total sum for February does not match. **The total should be '5'** .

```
New Customers = //Cus
VAR CustomerTM = VALUES(Customer[Client])
VAR PriorCustomer = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Customer[Client]),
FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Customer,Customer[Branch]),
'Customer'[ETD] > Min('Customer'[ETD] ) - Parameter[Parameter Value] && 'Customer'[ETD] < MIN('Customer'[ETD])))
return
COUNTROWS(
EXCEPT(CustomerTM,PriorCustomer))
```

[image]
After looking into it for so many days, I still have no clue about it..
What are the most common issues that cause this problem and how do I fix it ?

Appreciate any help you can provide.
Thank you!

Attached with the pbix: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SVBM5Tqizqq3pBHl10fwcLV-l7LbwhS7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Nick, looks strange. Can you explain the filter condition by words `'Customer'[ETD] > Min('Customer'[ETD] ) - Parameter[Parameter Value] && 'Customer'[ETD] < MIN('Customer'[ETD])` . I mean, what do you expect to gain with it?

Comment: Hi Mik, good day! This formula calculates the customers who have purchased something in the current month but haven’t purchased anything in the 180 days (I have set parameter to 180) prior to that.
Here's the blog I get the idea, 
https://blog.enterprisedna.co/calculate-the-total-of-new-clients-youre-onboarding-every-month-advanced-dax/

Comment: In the blog, this guy uses a separate data table. I also can't get the point of the filter expression. May be you can ask  him for a clarification - how it's works. In my understanding it's incorrect.

Comment: I can create a mesure for you purpose but it will be a little bit different to what you have now. Anyhow it will be ineresting to know how the Filter() works.

Comment: Dear Mik, thank you for your attention to this matter! I have asked for clarification, but I have not received any useful information

Answer (score 1):

It is this line in your measure.

```
'Customer'[ETD] < MIN('Customer'[ETD])
```

SCCCORKUL has two values in the filter context with two separate dates. If you make the dates the same, then you get the answer you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Dear @David, appreciate for your response.
Would it be possible to get sum 5 even if I didn't change any of the dates? Because the date cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm just pointing out the issue. Your dates can stay the same but your measure will need to change. I have no idea what you're trying to calculate so can't advise.

Comment: Hi David ,This blog gave me the idea and formula. I just chg one line to filter by branches.
https://blog.enterprisedna.co/calculate-the-total-of-new-clients-youre-onboarding-every-month-advanced-dax/

Comment: Good stuff. Don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: HI @David, the expression seems strange for me, I mean - `'Customer'[ETD] < MIN('Customer'[ETD])` ? How Filter() can return anything if min can not be larger then anything. Or I have inccorect understanding? Thank you in advance for your opinion.

Comment: I never understood what it was trying to do either. I merely pointed out why Nick was seeing the result he was.

Answer (score 0):

Nick I've got the point. Your measure is working as it should - it is correct. Both of results sum=4 and 5 in the table are correct. The thing is in a different filter context in the table. The measure calculate result for each row separately. When you are in the table your filter context is: Branch, year-month and Customer. It means, that when the measure calculate for instance PRIMANPET, the `Min('Customer'[ETD] )= 22 feb 2022` then you get the first date `22 feb 2022 - 180`. For LEEGASPKG the `Min('Customer'[ETD] )= 21 feb 2022` and the expression - `Min('Customer'[ETD] ) - Parameter[Parameter Value]` gives you an other first date. You have a different `Min('Customer'[ETD] )` for each customer. When it comes for the total the context is: Branch and year-month (no Customer is in the context) and the `Min('Customer'[ETD] ) = 01 Feb 2022` in the context for each customer. So, it the total context you get SCCCORKUL for PriorCustomer, and in the table row context - not. You can check it - If you change parameter to a lower then you get 5 it total. Sorry for my english, hope you got the point, ask if not, i'll improve it ).

This measure is not that short, but more simple and it works the way you wish.

```
New Customers2 = 

VAR curCust=
SUMMARIZE(
    Append1
    ,Append1[Client]
    ,Append1[ETD]
    ,Append1[Branch] -- new
)

VAR curCustFirstDate =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        curCust
        ,"firstDay",Calculate(MAX(Append1[ETD]))-Parameter[Parameter Value]
    )
VAR curCustRowsQty =      
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        curCustFirstDate
        ,"qty"
                ,
                VAR mindate=[firstDay] 
                VAR currentDay=[ETD]
                VAR branch = [Branch] -- new
                Var client = [Client]
                RETURN 
                    CALCULATE(
                        COUNTROWS(Append1)
                        ,ALL(Append1)  -- new
                        ,Append1[ETD]>mindate
                        ,Append1[ETD]<=currentDay
                        ,Append1[Branch]=branch -- new
                        ,Append1[Client]=client
                    )
    )
VAR curCustFiltred=
        FILTER(
            curCustRowsQty
            ,[qty]=1
        )
RETURN  
    COUNTROWS(
        curCustFiltred
    )
```

Comment: Dear Mik, Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and for explaining the details. I really appreciate your help.
As I have appended some data and tested with your code, I found that if there are more than one branch for filter selection, the total seems a bit off
For PEN branch, 'MCD' client should consider new customer in month Feb 2022.
However, the MCD has been left out of your code.
Here's the pbix,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oi1Xe6-lP9sPofPYZIOzRWjWLemFzXXn/view?usp=sharing

Thank for the help!

Comment: I corrected it a little bit. Please, check.

Comment: It is possible, I believe, to make a shorter measure. But this one is easy to a edit. So, if you are interested to have other solution, then open a new question ). By the way, I want to thank you for the very usefull question it let me get deeper into FILTER() function, so I've got a great experience due to the case ).